# SmartClient: How to use modal window

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, smartgwt, smartclient

I want to develop an application in SmartClient using javascript. In that application, it takes 
inputs like price range and category. On form submit, without reloading the page it will send 
request to server and will get the list of items.few of them will be displayed after submit(on step 2)
and other will be displayed on 3rd step. And there will be a database query fired after step-2 and step-3

Structure to display items details contains item_pic, Item_name, item_price and availability.

How can i use modality window(in SmartClient) for this?

i saw an example at this URL: http://www.smartclient.com/?skin=Enterprise#modality
but i couldnt understand what type of programming is it?
and how to use that example to make my application?

Answer (score 4):

They have attached JavaScript associated with the code. Two basic properties of Window are applied to get a Window having Modality:

1. IsModal = true;
2. ShowModalMask = true.

Answer (score 1):

That's javascript(I guess JSNI Code impl) based implementation. For java code implementation of similar example refer: http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#layout_windows_modality. 
You can achieve the modality by simply setting setIsModal(Boolean) of the corresponding dialog box to true.

Answer (score 0):

Well the programming done here is very simple.  If you are good in java-script then try to learn `JSON` (java script object notation) and you would find it simple.

`JSON` is becoming popular data interchange medium.  It's light weight, easy to parse, and consumes less traffic.