# How to disable clicking or key-pressing the whole page with smartgwt

Tags: javascript, gwt, smartgwt

I'm building a project with using smartgwt.

There's a function I want to add.

That is, before I receive the result returned by the server side, I want to forbid
the user accessing the webpage, including clicking and key-pressing.

It's like a pop-up waiting or loading circle or text.
But the background is still my webpage.

Is there any object I can use in the smartgwt or gwt ??
Thanks!!

Comment: Take a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819583/smartclient-how-to-use-modal-window/4825341#4825341 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772234/smartgwt-modal-window/14807505#14807505 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160443/i-have-a-modal-window-implemented-in-smartgwt-how-can-i-close-it-when-someone/5164049#5164049

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will be to use a progressbar.

SmartGWT offers one:

```
com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Progressbar
```

I don't no the SmartGWT Progressbar, the ProgressBar from Sencha is a modal dialog which disable screen input as long as it is visible. Otherwise you can use a GlasPanel or a popup.